# Python telebot не работает проверка подписки

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

есть вот такой код:

```
import telebot 
from telebot import *
import requests
import json

bot = telebot.TeleBot('My_token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])  
def start_command(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello")
    print(message.from_user.id)
    print('2')
    CHAT_ID = -....
    USER_ID = ....
    result = bot.get_chat_member(CHAT_ID, USER_ID)
    print(result)
    print("ok")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

и в result он мне возвращает данные пользователя который не разу не вступал в группу хотя должен был выдавать ошибку что пользователь не состоит в группе

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в result есть слово "status:" и там будет написано member вступил, left вышел, creator создатель и тд.